# Why ruby on Rails is agile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, agile

I'm always hearing that RoR is good for Agile implementation. Could someone plaese summarize this statement  and explain me why with some examples.
P.S  I can't read "Agile Web Development with Rails" yet.

Comment: I can't understad, it's a very interesting question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools are never agile in the matter of software engineering. Tools support in being agile. Ruby on rails is a framework to rapidly build basic functionalities with ease and **Agile** in most minds is a way to build your system without having the knowledge of every requirement needed by your system.

So tools which support the developers to rapidly bootstrap a software or change functionalities rapidly help you in being agile. Because most of the times the understanding of "How things work" differs between the customer and the developer perspective.

Aligning those perspectives is a success factor on every project and most of the times it is better to show something for a common understanding than painting some flow charts, uml charts or whatever which imply domain knowledge.

Another thing is if you may bootstrap a project rapidly you may react on reordering of priorities more flexible.

For the nitpickers.: Agile is a buzzword. There are lots of definitions and different understandings whats agile is and it may always be that my view on being agile or developing agile differs from some other definitions.

Comment: +1: "Tools support in being agile".